# JMS Library - Robot Framework Install

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm looking for some library that connects the robot framework with MQ IBM.
I found a lib called JMS.

However, I didn't find any link that displays pip install robotframework...
Could someone tell me what is the name I add to do the installation?
The link, but without the command to install:
http://ilkkatoje.github.io/robotframework-jmslibrary/1.0.0/robotframework-jmslibrary.html

Do you have any other library that you think is better?

Comment: reason why you don't get that from pypi is that the library was written in java and was intended to be used with Jython ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Python library like `pymqi` see https://pypi.org/project/pymqi/

There are some getting started samples at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Python